# Install clickhouse-server-20.3.8.53 on centos and get a version of 20.4.2.9

Tags: clickhouse

My origin clickhouse version was `19.14.7.15`.

```
$ clickhouse-client
ClickHouse client version 19.14.7.15 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 19.14.7 revision 54425.
```

And I installed a version of `20.3.8.53`.

```
$ sudo yum install -y clickhouse-server-20.3.8.53
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Excluding 3 updates due to versionlock (use "yum versionlock status" to show them)
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package clickhouse-server.noarch 0:19.14.7.15-2 will be updated
---> Package clickhouse-server.noarch 0:20.3.8.53-2 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: clickhouse-common-static = 20.3.8.53-2 for package: clickhouse-server-20.3.8.53-2.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package clickhouse-common-static.x86_64 0:19.14.7.15-2 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: clickhouse-common-static = 19.14.7.15-2 for package: clickhouse-client-19.14.7.15-2.noarch
---> Package clickhouse-common-static.x86_64 0:20.3.8.53-2 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package clickhouse-client.noarch 0:19.14.7.15-2 will be updated
---> Package clickhouse-client.noarch 0:20.4.2.9-2 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: clickhouse-common-static = 20.4.2.9-2 for package: clickhouse-client-20.4.2.9-2.noarch
repo.yandex.ru_clickhouse_rpm_stable_x86_64/filelists_db                                                                                                              | 1.2 MB  00:00:00
--> Running transaction check
---> Package clickhouse-common-static.x86_64 0:19.14.7.15-2 will be updated
---> Package clickhouse-common-static.x86_64 0:19.14.7.15-2 will be updated
---> Package clickhouse-common-static.x86_64 0:20.3.8.53-2 will be an update
---> Package clickhouse-common-static.x86_64 0:20.4.2.9-2 will be an update
---> Package clickhouse-server.noarch 0:19.14.7.15-2 will be updated
---> Package clickhouse-server.noarch 0:19.14.7.15-2 will be updated
---> Package clickhouse-server.noarch 0:20.3.8.53-2 will be an update
---> Package clickhouse-server.noarch 0:20.4.2.9-2 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                         Arch                          Version                              Repository                                                          Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 clickhouse-server                               noarch                        20.4.2.9-2                           repo.yandex.ru_clickhouse_rpm_stable_x86_64                         76 k
Updating for dependencies:
 clickhouse-client                               noarch                        20.4.2.9-2                           repo.yandex.ru_clickhouse_rpm_stable_x86_64                         55 k
 clickhouse-common-static                        x86_64                        20.4.2.9-2                           repo.yandex.ru_clickhouse_rpm_stable_x86_64                        112 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package (+2 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 112 M
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
(1/3): clickhouse-client-20.4.2.9-2.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                        |  55 kB  00:00:00
(2/3): clickhouse-server-20.4.2.9-2.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                        |  76 kB  00:00:00
(3/3): clickhouse-common-static-20.4.2.9-2.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                 | 112 MB  00:00:05
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                         19 MB/s | 112 MB  00:00:05
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Updating   : clickhouse-common-static-20.4.2.9-2.x86_64                                                                                                                                1/6
  Updating   : clickhouse-client-20.4.2.9-2.noarch                                                                                                                                       2/6
  Updating   : clickhouse-server-20.4.2.9-2.noarch                                                                                                                                       3/6
warning: /etc/init.d/clickhouse-server created as /etc/init.d/clickhouse-server.rpmnew
warning: /etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service created as /etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service.rpmnew
Path to data directory in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml: /var/lib/clickhouse/
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/clickhouse-server/preprocessed': File exists
  Cleanup    : clickhouse-server-19.14.7.15-2.noarch                                                                                                                                     4/6
  Cleanup    : clickhouse-client-19.14.7.15-2.noarch                                                                                                                                     5/6
  Cleanup    : clickhouse-common-static-19.14.7.15-2.x86_64                                                                                                                              6/6
  Verifying  : clickhouse-client-20.4.2.9-2.noarch                                                                                                                                       1/6
  Verifying  : clickhouse-server-20.4.2.9-2.noarch                                                                                                                                       2/6
  Verifying  : clickhouse-common-static-20.4.2.9-2.x86_64                                                                                                                                3/6
  Verifying  : clickhouse-server-19.14.7.15-2.noarch                                                                                                                                     4/6
  Verifying  : clickhouse-common-static-19.14.7.15-2.x86_64                                                                                                                              5/6
  Verifying  : clickhouse-client-19.14.7.15-2.noarch                                                                                                                                     6/6

Updated:
  clickhouse-server.noarch 0:20.4.2.9-2

Dependency Updated:
  clickhouse-client.noarch 0:20.4.2.9-2                                                     clickhouse-common-static.x86_64 0:20.4.2.9-2

Complete!
```

After I restarted my server I got this

```
$ sudo systemctl restart clickhouse-server.service
 $ clickhouse-client
ClickHouse client version 20.4.2.9 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 20.4.2 revision 54434.
```

As I can see, version of `20.4` is not a stable version. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: downgrade it following this instruction: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/getting-started/install/#from-rpm-packages

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/11005