# Upgrade ClickHouse On Centos

Tags: centos, yum, clickhouse

I am using old version of Clickhouse  19.17.6 revision 54428 and I want to upgrade to the latest stable one.
i need help with to which command to run

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868415/install-clickhouse-server-20-3-8-53-on-centos-and-get-a-version-of-20-4-2-9

Comment: @vladimir question in your link isn't really about upgrade, it's about installation, which isn't what OP is concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

sudo yum install -y clickhouse-server-20.4.2.9 clickhouse-client-20.4.2.9 clickhouse-common-static-20.4.2.9